# Little oh notation question: $x^{o(1)}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having a bit of trouble with a little oh notation question. If I have $x^{o(1)}$, am I right in thinking that as $x \rightarrow \infty$ that the exponent goes to 0 (and the base goes to 0). I have to show that $x^{o(1)} = O(\log x)$ but I'm a bit stuck. I'm erroneously stuck thinking that $x^{o(1)} - 1 = O(1)$ for some reason and can't see any other way to get the result. Any hints?

Comment: It all depends on how quickly the exponent goes to $0$. For example, if the exponent is $1/\log\log x$, then $x^{o(1)}\to\infty$.

Comment: If $x$ is the base, then it obviously goes to $\infty$. The base of the log stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to prove is incorrect in general, that means there are functions $r(x) \in o(1)$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{r(x)}}{\log x} = \infty,$$

which contradicts $x^{r(x)} \in O (\log x)$.

An example would be

$$r(x)=\frac{2\log(\log x)}{\log x}.$$

To see this, consider

$$\log (x^{r(x)})=r(x)\log x = 2\log(\log x) = \log \left((\log x)^2\right)$$

which implies

$$x^{r(x)} = (\log x)^2$$

and finally

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{r(x)}}{\log x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\log x = \infty.$$

OTOH,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} r(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2\log(\log x)}{\log x} = \lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{2\log y}{y}$$

if we substitute $y=\log x$ and observe that with $x\to\infty$ also $y\to \infty$. The last limit is clearly $0$ (if you don't know this directly, apply the rule of l'Hospital).

That means we finally get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} r(x) = \lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{2\log y}{y} = 0,$$

which implies $r(x) \in o(1)$.

So depending on where this problem comes from, you will need to get more knowledge about what I called $r(x)$. Just knowing $r(x) \in o(1)$ is not enough to get the conclusion you want.

Comment: This is helpful! What I'm trying to show is that if I have $O(x^{1/2 + o(1)}) = O(x^{1/2} \log x)$ and I'm not sure if I need more information to get to this. It's a bit baffling for me honestly.

Comment: This is equivalent to the problem here. When you create the qotient, the $x^{1\over 2}$ from both terms will cancel, and you get this problem. So you 'need' more info about the $o(1)$, as I wrote.